# Not able to Write single quotes into double quotes with a terminal

Tags: ruby, linux

Im trying to make a file with the following line of code inside (ruby line)

```
puts File.read('/users')
```

This is what I should be getting if I print that out.

The problem is that I'm not able to do that in the terminal. I tried a lot of things such as:

```
echo "puts File.read('/users')" > file_with_line.rb

echo puts File.read('/users') > file_with_line.rb
```

And other variants but none of them worked all of them give me an error or this output `puts File.read(/users)` without the single quotes.

It seems pretty easy and silly but I have not had success finding the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File.read('.users')` will not create file. It just reads the file. If you want to read a file first create it with `File.write('/users', 'some text contents')`. and then try to read with the same command you are trying with. Note: `puts` is not needed, `File.read` is enough to output the file contents.

Comment: @prashant Thanks for the answer! Maybe I didn't explain my self right. I will be put that line of code inside a file, the line of code itself has nothing to do with creating a file. `echo puts File.read('/users') > file_with_line.rb` I just wanna to be able to execute from a file, but the problem is that Im having trouble with the single quotes

Comment: I have tested the command in Windows and Linux -- it produced expected result. Only possible explanation is that you do not have _write_ permission on location where you try to create the file.

Comment: @Unknown : So the problem is basically, that you want to create a text file with your program, without using a text editor? This is not a Ruby problem, so I suggest to remove the _ruby_ tag. In your concrete example, the first approach should work, since you did not get an error message when doing the `echo`. What did `cat file_with_line.rb` show you instead?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to close your double quotes:

```
echo "puts File.read('/users')" > file_with_line.rb
```

Here's a complete example:

```
bash-5.1$ echo "puts File.read('/users')" > file_with_line.rb
bash-5.1$ cat file_with_line.rb 
puts File.read('/users')
```

Comment: I miss wrote on the post, I tried like that and didn't work

Comment: @Unknown Please try to be much more specific. For example, instead of saying "I tried this" say "I put the following line in a file called test.rb and ran `ruby test.rb`", or instead of "gave me an error" say "gave the error ``-:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `file_with_line' for main:Object (NameError)``"

Comment: @Unknown : What does _didn't work_  mean? Could you perhaps think of a more helpful description of the problem you are encountering?